# Invalid SOA objects under SOAINFRA user

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, soa

I have found two invalid objects in oracle database which belong to SOAINFRA user in SOA application. It's can be recompiled and can be turn to valid state

```
ALTER PROCEDURE PURGE_RUNTIME_WITH_TIMEOUT COMPILE;
ALTER PROCEDURE PURGE_B2B_INSTANCES_DOWN COMPILE;
```

but I want to know what made the object to became invalid. I searched but couldn't find anything which gives me the actual reason. I got the below note from oracle site:

There is an issue caused by the existence of foreign key constraints in the `Oracle B2B` table. When dropping the partition, the `B2B` partition purge is invoked, the foreign key constraints must be disabled before dropping the partition and enabled afterward. To perform this action, execute the `PL/SQL` procedures `b2b_disable_constraints` and b2b_enable_constraints at the appropriate steps in the above procedure. Because foreign keys are enabled and disabled in these procedures, it is not recommended to run them on a live system.

[Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/integration.1111/e10226/soaadmin_partition.htm)

Also, I checked in database but there is no partitioned table.